# Can an internal class have public functions and variables in Swift/Xcode 9?

Tags: swift, xcode

It might sound a trivial question but I am newbie in Swift, I was wondering whether an internal class can have public methods and variables that I would like to use from that class.

Let's say something like this( as example)

```
internal class myService: InheritService {

public var x : Int32 = 0

public func sum (_ a: Int32, _b: Int32) -> Int32 {

 return (a + b)

}}
```

Can I sue then function sum and variable x from outside?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just trie it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it can't. Any access modifiers of properties or methods contained in a first class citizen such as a class, struct, protocol or enum will always be overwritten by that of the containing definition.

Think about it this way, if you can't see a dog, how can you check how many legs it has?

```
struct Dog {
    public var legCount: Int = 3
}
```

Comment: then I don't understand why but I can have access to the method and variable of my internal class

Comment: Do you know what internal means? It means 'accessible from within the module in which it is defined'. Basically, unless `myService` is defined in a separate module such as a Framework, you'll be able to access it just fine. See [this](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-4-access-levels/) article for more info.

Comment: Understood, my lack of swift knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Although the following code **will compile without warnings**, it doesn't really make sense as other comments suggest.

```
internal class Animal {
  public let name = "Bob"
}
```

Therefore, you might want to add a lint rule such as [lower_acl_than_parent](https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/lower_acl_than_parent.html) to your codebase to prevent you from having code like this.